# How to deal with people looking at their mobile phone during my presentation?

Tags: etiquette, presentation, seminars, technology

I was invited to give a research seminar in another department, and two professors kept looking at their mobile phones while I was talking. They were doing this at the start of my talk, and they kept looking at their mobiles for a fairly long amount of time, maybe 15 minutes, without interruption.

My personal view on this is to be tolerant. I accept that nowadays “technology is in our pockets” and the web offers infinite opportunities for distraction. Moreover, people may look at their smartphones for scholarly reasons, for example they may be doing a quick search for literature related to the topic being presented. I do not know for sure what people are doing on their mobiles, and it’s not up to me to discipline their behaviour.

That being said, I think that the basic rules of politeness and consideration for each other’s’ feelings still have a role and place. For example, if I know that I am going to be distracted during a talk, then I sit at the back of the room and try to get unnoticed. If I can’t resist the lure of the smartphone, then I keep it under the table and I try to look at it only for a short time. And maybe add an apologetic smile.

But on that occasion, both professors were sitting in front of me on the first row, with their mobiles in full view, and acted as if my talk didn’t matter. I must add that both professors are much higher in status than me, also the university where I gave the talk is of much higher rank than my university.

I didn’t want a confrontation so I pushed all the unpleasant feelings aside, and I concentrated on my talk. However, I recently thought about this episode, and it occurred to me that maybe I needed to show more assertiveness. Not for the sake of my ego (I don’t care about these two and what they do in seminars), but because assertiveness shows that we care about our research and our value as scholars, regardless of our status.

How would you deal with people overtly and persistently looking at their mobile device (phone, laptop, etc.) during your talk?

Comment: "**professors**", they're tricky, but a cardboard box, some crayons, a few sweets, and the promise of a Happy Meal may have worked, but trying to keep them focused for more than 5 min's is a universal issue ;)

Comment: Be glad they didn't have laptops and typed furiously the whole time... \*sigh\*

Comment: On a related note, there are some people who are excellent multi-taskers - I've seen this behavior a couple of times, and oftentimes, the first row cell phone typers still ask to-the-point questions at the end of the talk.

Comment: They neither slept nor graded course work.

Comment: Just ignore it. Used to be, people just stared off into space or scribbled notes on a piece of paper - their attention spans were never any longer than they are now.

Comment: FWIW, I think it's extremely polite for someone to come to hear to my talk,  even if they apparently need to do other things or are not very interested. So when I see someone not concentrating, I usually don't have any unpleasant feelings. But I guess you can't force yourself to think the same way, so this probably doesn't qualify as an answer.

Comment: At a concert recently, I saw something which really worked well, where the performer, instead of asking everybody to turn off their phones, said something like "Welcome to <venue>, my name is <artist>, I hope you enjoy my show, and please don't forget to your phones back on after the concert!"

Comment: If you knew one of their cell numbers, you could call them and ask them to please look up and pay attention.

Comment: @Raphael are you opposed to live texing then?

Comment: This is the most effective way I have seen. Stop your presentation, stay quiet and look at them in as neutral a way as possible. Eventually the entire room will focus on them, and they will get the message and stop, or someone in the audience who is actually interested in what you have to say will state the obvious for you. When they put their devices away or get up and walk out, then continue. No one likes that kind of attention and it will set the tone for the rest of the presentation, so people will be less apt to draw that attention. If someone does it again, stop again.

Comment: And I cannot believe most all of the answers here... The lack of self-esteem is mind boggling and it is no wonder that so many people view academics in general and science in particular with such disdain. What you do should matter or you shouldn't be doing it at all. If you are not willing to expect respect from a room full of colleagues then how do you expect to get the tax paying public, who is likely footing the bill for your research to take you seriously. Are you all so beaten down by your PIs and Mentors that you expect to be treated like an unimportant nobody?

Comment: @Kimball In a research talk, I find it hard to believe they TeX along. Especially if they don't look up. So if they TeX, they probably write on their latest paper, or their slides for their own talk later. Both are unacceptable. If they *do* TeX along, they should get a *very* silent keyboard, and some might say they'd still demonstrate desinterest.

Comment: @AMR I doubt that works when the speaker is a PhD student and the distracted senior professor an internationally famous researcher in the field.

Comment: @gerrit, people can be powerful without status, if they have an expectation that they will be shown respect and that what they have to say and the work that they have done matters. If nothing else it will make that point to everyone else in the room, even if the boors don't get the message. And how do you think those "internationally famous" people got to be who they are? They lived with the expectation that what they did mattered and that they should be taken seriously, probably as far back as the playground. And if you don't feel that what you do is that important, then stop doing it.

Comment: @AMR That all sounds very noble, but as an early career scientist depends on recommendations from senior scientists to progress in xyr career, getting a reputation to call out and embarrass inconsiderate seniors is not helpful.

Comment: @gerrit, that is where you are wrong. They might not get those two professors recommendations, but they will get much better ones as the rest of the people in the room will say to themselves that this person respects their work enough to expect respect from everyone present, and that what they are doing matters. I didn't say throw a temper tantrum, I just said wait. Silence is an incredibly powerful thing in public speaking. And who's to say that you aren't affording them the respect to wait until their ultra important, couldn't wait message is finished before you continue.

Comment: @AMR What here makes you think that academians here don't expect to be respected? And do you think that embarrassing audience (e.g. by being silent until they stop) helps them gain respect?

Comment: @AMR terrible, terrible advice. This means you let yourself and the whole audience get distracted by a trivial hit to your ego. **Just ignore them**.

Comment: One idea, albeit a horrible idea, but a good EMP could do the trick...

Comment: @Warlord099 Marvelous idea! "Talk, talk, talk, important stuff, talk, and now I will demonstrate my pocket-sized EMP which can be set for a 30, 50, or 70 yard radius."

Comment: No matter how you package it...it is just plain rude!!

Comment: Are we in 2015 or in 1915?

Comment: @Warlord099 I have been saying for a long time that we need WLAN, 3G, ... jammers in seminar and lecture rooms. (In a few years, how would we take exams otherwise?)

Comment: I'm a little boggled that people find this rude. I could understand if they were making noise, or interrupting because they have to ask a question because they missed something, but to be upset because they aren't pretending to give you their undivided attention?

Comment: @Hurkyl: My mind is boggled that your mind is boggled. This is incredibly rude behavior.

Comment: @Ben: Is it rude because it is actually doing something problematic, or is it just one of those things where some people get offended if you don't properly participate in a ritual?

Comment: @DCTLib: Did you actually verify that they were *multi*-tasking? As in, do you know they weren't just idly looking at their phones and actually putting all their attention on the presentation they were hearing? (i.e. Do you know if they were also paying attention to their phones, rather than merely looking at them?)

Comment: Being a polite and considerate individual, I always try to look interested and awake during presentations. It is, of course, all an act. In reality, I am thinking of other things, like all the mail I have to read.

Comment: @Mehrdad Well, they were typing - for this action to make sense, they must reserve some cognitive resources for that task.

Comment: I'm reading this article right now whilst in presentstion :D

Comment: Someone is listening carefully to what you saying.  Give the presentation to the best of your ability for that person.  Like Ian McKellen says in ''The Dresser'', when you go out on stage to perform a play someone understands what you are doing, so you do it for that person, even if everyone else in the audience doesn't care and is not paying attention.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

My attitude to life is to spare my mental capacities to things I can affect and change. Yes, it is annoying to see people at a workshop not paying attention. No, there is nothing I can do in the moment that would (i) change their behavior, while (ii) not make me look petty.

So, disengage from these feelings. Focus on those members of your audience who pay attention and interact with you. Make a resolution to have a great first slide for your next talk that may sway one of the two (or maybe both!) to get pulled into the talk. These are the things I can affect.

Comment: Exactly this. After all, if you're on a conference, most likely your topic is too special to maybe 80% of your audience to be truly understandable. The 20% that understand are likely following you even if they seem not to be (maybe looking up a relevant paper on arXiv or whatever). The 80% need to know roughly what you're working on, and they can probably sight-read it; they've been doing that for ages, at every conference and they master this ability.

Comment: I'd like to pretend that those who look at the phones or laptops just look up something related, but in reality they're most likely simply not paying attention at all. Either way, it's not something that I can fix that very moment. It just wants me to learn to make better presentations.

Comment: What @WolfgangBangerth said. There have been times where I've had to text a colleague to arrange a time to meet up in the next half hour. I've also had a dead laptop battery and have needed to take a note or two on my phone (about the presentation). Some—but not all!—behaviors are acceptable. When speaking, focus on those that are paying attention, and hope that those who look like they aren't really are.

Answer (score 75):

I'll offer a dissenting point of view.

I often use my mobile device (smartphone, laptop, whatever) during a talk - because I'm taking notes on it!

I used to write my notes on paper, then transcribe them to my giant brain dump TXT file (very easy to search through, which is why scanning is not a solution)... until I noticed that I always put off the transcribing part until I had lost my paper notes. Since then, *especially if a talk is relevant*, I have been taking notes on my phone, so I can copy & paste the notes directly into my TXT.

Don't immediately jump to the conclusion that people fiddling with their electronics are not paying attention.

(If I'm using my laptop, I'll sit in the back, since I know that my keyboard can be distracting.)

Comment: When I pull out my phone during a talk, it's often because I want to look up a definition or refresh my memory of a relevant detail.

Comment: I've even pulled out my phone to look up information for a colleague (who did not own a smartphone) sitting next to me who was wondering about something in the talk.

Comment: This justifies *occasional* use of a device, but not permanent use.

Comment: I use a laptop/smartphone during a talk, because I need something to do after I can't follow the talk anymore. The pacing of a talk is always wrong. The presenter spends too much time on the parts I feel obvious, while not describing the background and the novel/nontrivial parts in sufficient detail. Sometimes I need to think about something the presented said for a while, but I can't pause the talk while I do so. As a result, I usually lose the track of a research talk after the first few minutes, even when I actively try to listen.

Comment: You can tell the difference when someone is actively listening and taking notes and someone is just taking up space and sexting someone or playing Words With Friends. You know full well that what the OP is describing is not what you are describing.

Comment: This is a brilliant point, since it allows the speaker to *assume* that everyone is taking notes even though in fact they're not paying attention at all. Everyone's happy.

Comment: This is a poor answer. If you seriously choose to take notes on your phone, you're either taking classes that are too simple or you are the biggest phone user in the Western world. I dare say typing it being fastest, writing and then retyping being second fastest and mobile typing being absolute slowest.

Comment: @insidesin: I am not talking about (and the question is not referring to) *lectures*, but to *seminars*. At least in my experience, I'll take much fewer notes in seminars or conference talks than in lectures, since it's quite enough to understand the main points, not the details (which you need to capture in a lecture). I agree that taking notes with a phone during lectures is a lot harder.

Comment: Seminars should be less notes, more interaction and more listening, so that's possibly even worse. But yes, I understand. I still think mobile note taking is a bit of a waste of time when there are so many better options available.

Comment: @insidesin, if I want to take copious notes (e.g. a lecture), there's no beating pen&paper, but if I'm not expecting to write much the phone is quick.  At a conference I'll often type onto my laptop -- most talks only lead to a few lines of notes, but I can get quite a lot down quickly if I need to.  Like the phone it's searchable. Mobile typing isn't necessarily slow especially if you're not too concerned with perfection -- its errors are sometimes odd though.

Comment: To be clear: are you only offended, or does their behaviour actually distract you? In the latter case, why not ask attendees to turn off their cellphones in a snarky/humorous way on slide 0?

Comment: With all due respect, while many people do take notes, I have sat behind many a thesis adviser checking their email or doing other work during their student's public defense. I get that the "important stuff" happens in the close door defense, but think of the example that sets!

Answer (score 48):

If you are presenting a topic and the audience do not take advantage of your experience and knowledge, it is their loss and not yours. However, two things came to my mind about this topic:

1. **Make Your Presentation More Interactive**: I'm not saying to bring big amplifiers and blast music and throw free t-shirts at the crowd, however you can engage the audience with the topic you are working on. You can ask them questions, about their prior knowledge about the topic, and build the presentation around that. If the presenter is looking at the ground, not paying attention to the audience, or not asking any questions, then they won't get the respect they deserve.
2. **Don't be Judgmental About the Audience Behavior**: Don't be an insecure presenter, and think negatively right away why the audience do this or that. Maybe they were tweeting how good your presentation is. You don't know what they are doing, so don't waste energy on why the audience is doing this or that, you are the captain in that room, and you should take control of your presentation and audience at the same time.

Comment: I don't think I could resist the lure of integrating a small, pointed (but friendly) dig at screen-watchers into the interactive part.

Comment: I agree that the best way to reduce smartphone usage is to be more engaging. However, I wouldn't throw away the free t-shirt idea so quickly – after all, it's hard to catch a free t-shirt with a cell phone in your hand. ;^)

Answer (score 24):

To echo some of the other answers and comments that suggest just trying to "get over it": the pre-cell-phone/internet version of this was senior faculty reading their mail: noisily ripping open envelopes, sometimes large manila envelopes with preprints sent (by physical mail), but invariably dozens of envelopes ripped open. Much noisier than looking at cell phones. Yes, you'd think that if they were away from their home campuses they'd not have piles of mail to go through... but in those days delaying looking at all the importuning physical mail was the analogue of today's delaying figuring out what to do with an inundation of email.

And then there was/is the style of "bringing a pad" to any talk: get some thinking done, and annotation of it, while allocating a little attention to the speaker. This does make sense if one is fairly expert, fairly experienced at "listening to talks", and so on. The remarks about "successful multitasking" are on the mark for experienced professionals: they often know fairly precisely how much attention is needed for a given task... and can control allocation... and thus get much more done each day.

The point is that it's not about cell-phone manner, it's about the culture of "listening to talks". Truly, from a fairly expert viewpoint, most of these talks have a very low (relative!) information rate. True, a person interested in making the speaker "feel good" would act the part... but if one is doing an awful lot of attendance-at-dubious-talks, the goal of "making the speaker feel better about themself" becomes less-clearly a high priority.

(Certainly being not-so-obvious about one's multi-tasking is a "grace", but/and it appears to be unrealistic to uniformly expect academics to aim for this...)

Comment: The assumptions resp. experiences underlying this answer begs the question: why do we give talks at all?

Comment: @Raphael, I guess sometimes we give talks because we _have_ _to_. Sometimes because we want to attempt to make more of an impact on others (by "affect", for example) than an inert PDF or piece of paper might. Sometimes that impact is "by being seen". Sure, often seminars are a high-noise environment... but, arguably, less noisy than "Internet". Not the ideal that one might have dreamed-of. Still, not clear that everyone wants a "heroic figure" (as in some famous seminars of the past) running things with an iron fist, etc, enforcing civility. Petty impoliteness is not the worst price to pay...

Comment: Oh, you make a good incidental point. The host of the seminar could enforce policies! That might actually be a suitable answer.

Comment: It's the speaker's job to create a talk which will keep the audience rapt. Some people will come as polite gesture to the inviter to fill up the audience; sometimes to discover something new to learn. But this politeness/interest needs to be matched by the speaker. If 200 people spend one hour of their life in a talk possibly not in their field of main interest, they deserve to get something out of it. This, to put it mildly, does not always happen. If people do sit discreetly in the back with open laptops, their goodwill to come possibly wasn't matched by the quality or relevance of the talk.

Answer (score 19):

I agree that their behavior was very rude, and it is best keep looking at smart phones or laptops during a talk to the absolute minimum.

Having said that, I think that anything else than what you have done (trying to ignore their behavior) will be very unlikely to have any positive outcome for you. If you would address their behavior, even in the politest way, they probably feel annoyed at you (or worse). I fail to see how you could benefit from this.

Comment: I absolutely loved the lecturers that enforced 'no mobiles', etc. in their lectures. Loved it! Albeit I am not stupid enough to waste a lecture like that on my phone *and* the lecture sizes were quite small... 30-60.

Comment: @insidesin My boss has established such a rule in approximately 200 students lectures. Even though he would, if push came to shove, have no actual way of enforcing the rule, students usually follow suit; they *are* dependent, after all. The feedback was overwhelmingly positive; motivated students realize that screens in their field of view are an awful distraction.

Answer (score 13):

### As a speaker, your job is to *speak*.

It's the hosts (or moderator's) job to make the environment welcoming for the speaker. If you want the audience to behave a certain way, talk to the host/moderator and ask them to mention and enforce it. Nobody has the job of demanding an audience's attention or respect.

It's pretty normal for people to sit through a talk because they were at the one before and the one after. To them, the present talk is a bit of a break. Is it distracting? It can be, especially to the presenter. Is it rude? Often, but not always, and it almost never is intended to be.

Think of your opportunity to talk—and your audience's attention—as a *privilege*, not a *right*. Be thankful for those who give you their attention, and ignore the rest. If you give a good presentation, it will be their loss.

Is there a breakdown of respect? *Yes.* Should we do our best to reverse it? *Yes*, but it begins with ourselves and with the youth. Teach your kids (if you have any) and your students (if you have any) and those who look up to you to be respectful.

**You can *earn* respect, but anyone who *demands* it looks bad.**

Comment: Heh! Yes, "demanding respect" leads to all sorts of troubles...

Answer (score 6):

It is somewhat rude and distracting to sit in the front row and obviously not pay attention. But tough luck. You're not a school teacher so you don't have the right to demand your audience's attention. Focus on the audience members who are paying attention to what you have to say: that will help you avoid the distractions, at the same time as directing your focus to the people who will benefit the most from it.

Answer (score 5):

For me, the main problem would be the distraction.

There is a technique used by some really good high school teachers.  Move around a bit while you are lecturing, spending just a little extra time in the zone near the distracting individual.  The additional proximity for a few moments will probably make the offending character(s) a little self-conscious and therefore less distracting.  You don't need to be blatant about it.  The more subtle the better this works.

The other thing you can do is pick up a manila folder or a couple of pieces of paper or something, and hold it in as discreet position as possible, that will block out the front-row in-use phone from your view.  This will help your concentration.

Comment: I've seen a speaker who would walk through the entire seminar room during his talk, all the way to the rear of the room and back.  It was very effective.  However, this was at a summer school with a senior speaker and a junior audience.  I don't know how it would be taken the other way around.

Comment: @gerrit As an audience member, I'd find that *extremely* annoying. When somebody is speaking to you, they stand in front of you, where you can see them, make eye contact, see their facial expressions and feel involved in the "conversation", even if the talk is one-way. If they stand behind me, they may as well be a loudspeaker.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Since the phone users are in the front row, you would not need to stand behind anyone.  Also note, you don't need to keep moving for the whole 50 minutes.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Depending on the size of the room, walking towards the back allows you to interact with those sitting in the back in the first place. As long as you balance it out, I don't see a huge problem with doing so.

Comment: @Raphael You can interact with people at the back of the room to a reasonable, though imperfect, extent while standing at the front. Walking to the back of the room means you've turned your back to the majority of your audience, strongly excluding them. Also, in most seminars, there are plenty of empty seats. If the people at the back wanted to be interacted with, they could usually have chosen to sit much closer to the front.

Comment: Guys, guys.  This is irrelevant.  The jerks with the phones were in the front row.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I like it a little, as long as I can hear. It's as if they're physically looking at and trying to understand the same problem you're looking at, it works well with new concepts, not so much 'standard theory'.

Comment: @gerrit: I had someone do that walk-to-the-back bit a few months ago (National Guard presenter on disaster preparedness). I found it very distressing (I *want* to pay attention to him, but with fixed seating he's moving out of my frame of vision), and in fact rather threatening (given the topic and that I took a defense class where allowing this would be taken as an opportunity to attack you).

Comment: @DanielR.Collins - I'll say it once more, the walk to the back idea is entirely tangential to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The vast majority of the people attending a seminar that is held regularly (e.g. every week on a fixed time) will do so on a routine basis. They may sometimes be very interested in the subject and on some other occasions they may be less interested. For some older professors this is their regular nap time.

Answer (score 4):

One more useful tactic to add to those already discussed: focus on the people who are enjoying your talk.

This trick was taught to me by a professor whose lecturing style I find excellent.  In every audience, there will be a range of reactions.  Some people will like the talk more than others, and if you let yourself notice *those* people, then their smiling and nodding will have a positive feedback effect on your emotions regarding the talk.  That in turn leads to a better talk, which leads to more smiles, etc.

The same happens in reverse: if you pay attention to the people ignoring or disliking your talk, then the negative emotional impact will tend to degrade your quality of delivery, feeding back in the opposite direction.

The wonderful final corollary: if you are in the audience for a friend and you want their talk to go well, [the best thing that you can do is to smile](http://www.au.af.mil/au/awc/awcgate/kline-listen/b10ch5.htm).

Answer (score 3):

You probably can't do much about them, unless their behaviour is so gross that you can get away with a "reverse heckle" from you to the audience. (E.g. "The next lemma is so obvious that you should be able prove it while playing a game on your iPad, so I'll press on...") Best to practice that at your local stand-up comedy club first, though ;)

I guess you were making some eye contact with the audience, otherwise you might not have noticed what was going on at all. A good strategy is to search out a few listeners who *are* paying attention, and concentrate your eye contact on them to maximize the amount of feedback you get. If you can pick out three or four people in different parts of the room, most of the rest of the audience will subconsciously assume you are "looking at them" as well.

The worst instance of this that has happened to me wasn't an academic seminar, but a musical concert where I was a soloist. A teenage daughter of one of the concert organizers was sitting on the front row and ignoring the concert completely while doing her school homework, with intermittent shuffling of paper, dropping of books and pens, etc. I remarked to the organizer afterwards that his daughter seemed to have enjoyed the music. The only response was a rather pained look.

Comment: Your suggestion is passive-agressive. It sounds as a joke, but it only turns out as a joke if you're known for making jokes and your audience knows you really well (in general, this works in small "closed" communities). Yes, you can be passive-agressive, but people hate being targets of this, and targets of the looks of other people. If you're ready to be hated, go for it.

Comment: I agree the "heckle" approach isn't for everybody or every occasion. If you can't "read" the audience to judge what their reaction will be, you probably shouldn't try it. I don't see anything passive-aggressive in the strategy in my second paragraph, though.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I wasn't enough specific.

Comment: "concentrate your eye contact" on a few good listeners -- excellent.

Answer (score 3):

*"How to deal with people looking at their mobile phone during my presentation?"*

You don't. As long as they don't make noise you should be happy they took the time to be there. If it helps, pretend they're telling all their friends about the awesome presentation they're attending. Now this one is culture dependent, but in case you feel your senior colleagues are being overly rude, or have offended your honor, you can always challenge them to a [duel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duel); just be careful before you slap them in the face with your glove since dueling is nowadays illegal in some countries and you don't want to go to jail just because someone didn't pay attention to your presentation.

Answer (score 2):

The mindset I have while teaching: if my students are bored during the class, it is **me** who is boring. It is my fault, so there is no point in getting upset with them. The same applies if people are sleeping: either I am boring them, or they are taking medication that makes them drowsy: either way, it is not their fault, and it is probably mine.

The same applies to a talk, it is *my responsibility* to be engaging, clear, and overall, make an useful presentation. With an extra catch: a research talk is something very specific, and cannot always be fully conveyed in the abstract. I have attended many talks that sounded interesting, but realised after five minutes that they were talking on a completely different level, or taking a radically different approach than what I am interested in. As an example, I would attend a talk about machine learning applied to biology interested in the machine learning bit, but it may turn out to be heavier on the biological part, and loose me quickly.

If I can't follow a talk, there is no point in me looking at the slides; so I better do something better than just wasting my time. We are all consenting adults, I don't have to go around policing people on what to do. Furthermore, if many people have chosen not to listen to me, it is a bad sign I should pick up and fix before my next talk.

Answer (score 1):

paul garret makes good point in a [comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/980/paul-garrett) that I think deserves its own answer.

If it is a regular thing, some ground rules may make sense: do not talk too long, take open-ended questions offline, do not take calls while attending, and -- maybe -- do not use electronic devices while somebody gives a talk.

Assuming there is a host for this seminar, i.e. the person who sends the invite, talk to them. Ask them to establish a set of rules *and enforce them*. You can propose a rule regarding your wishes.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dave Rose's answer

**The top thing that you can do is to keep the talk interesting.** That way people will be staring at your power point even if they have no idea what is on it. What I have noticed from my own experience both as an audience member and a speaker is that people drift off when there is something/anything at all that they do not understand.

So a lot of pictures, a lot of summary, a lot of predictability in your talk (like reusing slides but with different words), a lot of prompt words "When, Why, What, How..." but also make sure that all of them are satisfactorily explained.

For example:

1. A lot of people put a single picture/figure on a slide and then ramble on for 5 minutes. Remember your audience has to digest everything you say, which can be very difficult to follow the more technical the material. What I would do is to put just enough information underneath the figure on the power point slide so it is self-explained. So audience never feel like they have lost track of everything and my talk is like supplementary material.
2. Also the more technical the material, the more motivation it needs. For example, when some speakers are explaining a method or an algorithm, they quickly jump to the blackboard and start setting up the entire problem. My approach is always go for the simplest example imaginable to show the big idea, then lead the audience into more involved examples. I rarely use the black board by the way because audience tends to do their own little thing when you are showing your back to them, I use the blackboard to draw pictures, nothing more.
3. You can always bring your audience back when they drift off. You can adjust the tone of your voice, sound more excited "Look at this result, isn't this wonderful". I saw one very experienced presenter who inserts images of his children (along with other random stuff like animals) into the slides and let them do the talking. People are interested in kids. Do that.

**All in all there is a lot a presenter can do to make the talk interesting, and that is the KEY to keep your audience focused.** The more interesting it is, the less likely they will do something else like looking down at their phone or iPad or their Laptop. This works especially well for your front row audience.

Answer (score 0):

Someone is listening carefully to what you saying and will get something from your talk.  Give the presentation to the best of your ability for that person.  I have found this issue of short attention spans is getting increasingly worse because people are used to instant gratification with Youtube and things like this, so this is basically never going to stop, so just make the talk as engaging as you can.  Also, don't make the talk ''interactive'' and start picking on people to hold their attention, as that will just make people uncomfortable.

Like Ian McKellen says in ''The Dresser'', when you go out on stage to perform a play someone understands what you are doing, so you do it for that person, even if everyone else in the audience doesn't care and is not paying attention.

Answer (score -4):

It's a rough matter, in my opinion. And I have plenty of opinion; see [Technonomicon](http://tinyurl.com/technonomicon) for one tiny slice.

One way-heavy-handed thing you should not say (perhaps a commenter may have a better idea) is to say:

"*I've worked hard on all this presentation to give you my best, and I can't give you my best if your attention is split between me and a smartphone. So why don't we have a few minutes' silence to post off those last emails, or whatever will be distracting if we jump in, and then we'll all be in a position for the lecture to go well.*"

In a non-academic setting, there is a famous (blue-collar) restaurant where they ring an obnoxiously loud buzzer if someone is using the cell phone. The wall has a wall plaque saying, "We don't allow cell phones in this restaurant. If you are someone so important that you have to be on a cell phone, you should be eating someplace much more upscale."

Comment: Quoting CapeCode's comment to the original question: "terrible, terrible advice. This means you let yourself and the whole audience get distracted by a trivial hit to your ego. Just ignore them." You are stopping the talk and wasting everybody's time for a dubious gain in attention.